# Java JIT compiler optimisation for ternary operator

Tags: java, eclipse, ternary-operator, jit

While using ternary operator, it is very convenient to write code like

```
String name = employee.getName() != null ? employee.getName() : "";
```

than (most of the times) more efficient code like

```
String name = employee.getName();
if (name == null) {
    name = "";
}
```

**Q1.** I am interested to know how does the JIT compilers optimise this code.

While trying to find out answer over internet, even though I found couple of references but they were not covering this particular case.

I'm happy even if I get answer of

**Q2.** Easiest way to find out JIT compilers optimisation. (Some tool of plugin to eclipse.)

Comment: The Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler works on bytecode, not on source code, and is part of the Java VM (e.g. HotSpot or [OpenJ9](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/jit/)). Even the  bytecode created by `javac` or by the Eclipse compiler from the source code might be different due to different optimization. Could you please say which compiler you mean exactly?

Comment: You can tell the VM to log any jit:ing and see for yourself. Note that there are no guarantees that how this is implemented will not change over time. For more information see here : https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-evans-pt1-2266278.html

Comment: And by the way, in the first code snippet `name` is an effectively final variable, but in the second snippet not.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to give the infamous Stack Overflow answer: "wrong approach, do something else".

#### Why not do this

The thing you want to do here, this is called microbenchmarking. Brian Goetz wrote a [long post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02225/index.html) why this is usually a bad idea. Here are some highlights:

- Optimization depends on your OS and hardware too
- For most of the application this kind of speedups do not matter
- It is really difficult to measure only the thing you are interested in

#### What to do instead

You can measure you application. You can find the bottlenecks in your app with tools like [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/). And then you can optimize that part. The optimization is usually something creative, like use a cache, or scale only a specific part of the system.

#### But you really want to do microbenchmarks

In this case you can do the following two things:

- Read the bytecode and try to guess which would be faster in your setup (OS + hardware)
- Use the [microbenchmark](https://dzone.com/articles/microbenchmarking-comes-to-java-9) framework introduced in java. This will give you some numnbers. These numbers will be still setup-specific, and irrelevant to your application. However, the measuring part will be accurate.